# Vue components not rendering in Laravel blade.php file

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

Here's my set up:

This is the parent "Welcome.blade.php" set up. I'm including the relevant information since the file is pretty long:

```
<div id='app'>

<router-view></router-view>

</div>
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

Here is the app.js file:

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    
});
```

Here is the routes.js file:

```
let login= require('./components/auth/login.vue').default
let register= require('./components/auth/register.vue')

const routes = [
  {path: '/', component: login},
  {path: '/register', component: register}
]

export default routes;
```

The Login.vue component is this:

```
<template>
  <h1>Login page</h1>
</template>

<script>
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Register component is the same except instead of "Login page" it's "registration page." My question is, why doesn't the component render? I'm using laravel 8 and I've already installed Vue-router. Can anyone please help a newb?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your components in your app.js file as well. Like this:

```
Vue.component("example-component",require("./components/ExampleComponent.vue").default);
```